# URL amigável em página específica

Tags: php, htaccess

estou com um projeto do cliente em produção <strike>(locaweb então n tem cpanel :|)</strike> e tenho uma página de notícias e preciso deixar a mesma com URL amigável, a página **noticia.php** tem o seguinte código:
Como faço para deixar uma página e preciso deixar a mesma com URL amigável. A página `noticia.php`, e tem o seguinte código:

```
$urlpath    = $_SERVER['PATH_INFO'];
$urlpath    = $_SERVER['PATH_INFO'];
$paths        = explode('-', $urlpath);
$paths        = explode('-', $urlpath);
$i_item        = end($paths);
$i_item        = end($paths);
```

Ele pega o '/titulo-da-noticia-00', 00 que seria o ID da noticia, preciso que a URL 'http://localhost/noticia.php/titulo-da-noticia-00' também possa ser acessada por 'http://localhost/noticia/titulo-da-noticia-00'

O `.htaccess` atual está assim:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
```

Porém quando acesso na hospedagem recebo a seguinte mensagem de erro:

> HTTP Error 404.0 - Not Found The resource you are looking for has been
>   removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tente isso

**Arquivo noticias.php**

```
<?php
    $titulo = $_GET['noticia'];
    $id = end(explode('-',$titulo));
    echo $id;
?>
```

**Arquivo .htaccess**

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^noticia\/(.*)$ noticia.php?noticia=$1
```

**Url**

/noticia/titulo-da-noticia-222

Comment: Ainda continuo recebendo erro 404, mais a lógica está certa. Era apenas o 'noticias' no plural, valeuu!